# Error in url reference

Tags: bibtex

```
@online{amazon,
    author = {Amazon.com, Inc.},
    title = {Conditions of Use},
    year = {2012},
    url = {http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=footer_cou?ie=UTF8&nodeId=508088},
    urldate = {2014-02-08},
}
```

http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=footer_cou?ie=UTF8&nodeId=508088
make bib gives error in = (equal sign) and also & mark. What can i do to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure it is the answer you are looking for, but the `hyperref` package have a command `\url{ }` which allow to write a url address inside without necessity of scape special characters.

Comment: Just tell me how to do that. I'am a newbie.

Comment: Click the checkmark symbol just beneth the vote bottoms to the right of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`url`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\url{http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=footer_cou?ie=UTF8&nodeId=508088}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should code `&` marker `\&`; equal signs and also (probably) underscore signs as in `amsmath` symbols, between `$`. I had the same problem.

Comment: can you please write it up as a corrected url LaTeX accpets?

Comment: Here you go: {http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref{$=$}footer{$\_$}cou?ie=UTF8\&nodeId{$=$}508088}

Comment: I've just tried. Be sure to load \usepackage{amsmath} in the preamble